# Using Optional to map and return data which is not used

Tags: java, java-8

I am reusing the following optional optionalData which is declared and validated a few lines above.

If I reach here, this optional is definitely not empty.

The following code works fine as intended where I am putting and deleting some data.

Question is, is this the correct way to do it where I am using a map and not doing anything with the returned data?

Cos I am having to return a value here when I am actually not doing anything with it.

Only reason I am returning is cos there is a syntax error if I don't.

```java
optionalData
  .map(artData -> {
    Map<String, Object> currentData = artData.get(idKey);
    artData.remove(idKey);
    artData.put(getId(previousData), currentData);
    return artData.get(getId(previousData));
  });
```

Comment: The correct way would be to use [`ifPresent(...)`](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~iris/se/16/latestSpec/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent(java.util.function.Consumer)) instead of [`map(...)`](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~iris/se/16/latestSpec/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#map(java.util.function.Function)).

Comment: @Turing85 Thats certainly a cleaner way thanks. One thing that's throwing me off is that I've already validated an ifPresent way above on this optional. (Cant handle the logic shown here at that stage yet). Now I am doing an ifPresent here knowing very well that it is always true. Is that bad practice.

Comment: question then becomse why this block of code is not part of the 1st `ifPresent(...)` call. But to answer this, we would have to see all relevant code (and probably get some information on the domain). But honestly, I would not ponder too much about that. The check is inexpensive. I would be more concerned with readability. Furthermore, if the code works as intended, the question might be a better fit for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way would be to use [`Optional::ifPresent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent(java.util.function.Consumer)) instead of [`Optional::map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#map(java.util.function.Function)). The code would then transform to

```
optionalData
  .ifPresent(artData -> {
    Map<String, Object> currentData = artData.get(idKey);
    artData.remove(idKey);
    artData.put(getId(previousData), currentData);
  });
```